# Get object from a list in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am trying to get one account from some branch but somewhere i am missing something. This line is from method ->  but the result is <**main**.SavingAccount object at 0x000001F2563CEFD0>

```
class Branch:
    def __init__(self, branch_code, city):
      self.branch_code = branch_code
      self.city = city
      self.account_list = []
      self.loan_list = []

   def getAccount(self, acc_no):
       for account in self.account_list:
          if account.acc_no == acc_no:
              return account

    print(f2.getAccount(300005))
```

Comment: This looks correct to me - you have returned an object from the method and it is an object which is being printed. What _exactly_ are you expecting to be returned/printed?

Comment: Perhaps your issue is not with `getAccount`, but that you want to write a new `__str__` method for your `SavingsAccount` class? We can't really do that for you, since you haven't shown that code. But just knowing what you want to do may be all you need to do it yourself.

Comment: @Rhumborl i expect to print all details from the object. Or some details about this account. How can i do that?

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
class Branch:
    def __init__(self, branch_code, city):
        self.branch_code = branch_code
        self.city = city
        self.account_list = []
        self.loan_list = []

    def getAccount(self, acc_no):
       for account in self.account_list:
          if account == acc_no:
              return account

f2 = Branch(123,"NY")
f2.account_list=[111,222,300005]
print(f2.getAccount(300005))
```

Comment: The `account_list` has to be a list of objects, not numbers, as it needs to have an `acc_no` attribute

Comment: Just `return acc_no` would be a much easier solution if the accounts were just numbers.